# pandas: Join two data frames on columns of different types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join, merge

I am trying to join (merge) two pandas data frames: `df_A` and `df_B`. I want to join on `df_A.a_number = df_B.b_number`

However, `df_A.a_number` is of type `int64`, `df_B.b_number` is of type `object`. I tried to convert both of them to `str` before merge like below, but doesn't seem to work ...

```
df_A.a_number.astype('str')
df_A.dtypes

a_number       int64
a_set    object
dtype: object
```

and here is df_B:

```
df_B.b_number.astype('str')
df_B.dtypes

b_number    object
dtype: object
```

Then I try to join df_A and df_B:

```
df_C = pd.merge(df_A,df_B, how ='inner', left_on = ['a_number'], right_on = ['b_number'])
df_C
```

However, `df_C` is empty (which should't be). I am guess maybe because `a_number` and `b_number` are of different type and were not convert to `str` properly? Could anyone please advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try keeping `df_A.a_number` as `Int64` and convert the key in `df_B.b_number` to `Int64` as well.

```
df_B.b_number.astype('int')
df_C = pd.merge(df_A,df_B, how ='inner', left_on = ['a_number'], right_on = ['b_number'])
```

Answer (score 1):

As df_A.a_number is int64 and you want to convert it to str, you can do the following-

```
df_A.a_number = df_A.a_number.astype('str')
```

You were missing this assignment of the changed column I guess.
After you assigned the transformed df_A.a_number you can do the join and it should work.